# Is it possible to clear a TextArea AWT?

Tags: java, awt

How can I clear a TextArea from any current text? API doesn't show any clear() methods or something like this. I tried textArea.setText(""); but no luck. I'm adding stuff to it with append(); right now, just need to know how to clear it. Is there a way?

```
textArea.append("Text that needs to be cleared");
```

Comment: `setText` should work. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems like the reason it didn't work was that textArea.setText(""); did not work for some reason, but textArea.setText(" "); did.

textField.setText(""); works so I assumed textArea would work like this too.